# output a number — the number of students whose name (first_name) matches the name of at least one other student

Tags: sql, postgresql

Well, that is, there are two Johns and one Quill, you need to output the number of those people who have the same name. In one column there should be the total number of students with the same names

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count
FROM student
GROUP BY LOWER(first_name) HAVING COUNT(LOWER(first_name)) > 1;
```

it will output for each name the count, how to make the total?

Comment: Can you be more specific of what exactly you want your output to be ? For example you want 2 columns with the first be the sum of each name and the second to display the value of the name or you want a total sum of your records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the total, select from your query result and add the counts up.

```
SELECT SUM(cnt)
FROM
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM student
  GROUP BY LOWER(first_name)
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) counts;
```

Comment: I did the same, but some extreme case prevents me from completing the task

Comment: Which tells me nothing. Are you getting an error? Or unexpected results? What is this "extreme case"?

Comment: Well, that is, this is an assignment from school, and there are tests that this assignment does not pass. Mostly they are rare cases, that is, there are no such names, etc.

Comment: If there can be rows with no first name, you may want to add a WHERE clause to the subquery: `WHERE first_name <> ''` (which excludes empty strings and null).

Comment: Perhaps this is the code, when we do not have the same names, it does not output zero

Comment: When there are no identical ones, it is null, and it is necessary to output 0 for sure

Comment: Then use `COALESCE`: `SELECT COALESCE(SUM(cnt), 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the following:

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT(id)) as Total
FROM student
GROUP BY LOWER(first_name) HAVING COUNT(LOWER(first_name)) > 1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the aggregate function in the aggregate here?

Comment: In PLSQL it works, don't know about your case. Please try it.

Comment: You cannot nest aggregate functions. Oracle is the only DBMS I know of to allow that, but this is a feature I don't even see Oracle people using.